# sharepoint workflow stuck in a loop

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I have two sharepoint lists on which I have two custom workflows running automatically on Item added / updated. Now when workflow from list 1 is updating item on list 2, then item added event of list 2 triggers the workflow on it and then workflow 2 from list 2 starts to copy the item from list 2 to list 1 and this cycle continues...

How to stop this please guide .

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can implement this method

```
public static void SystemUpdate(this SPListItem item, bool incrementListItemVersion, bool doNotFireEvents)
{
    SPItemEventReceiverHandling rh = new SPItemEventReceiverHandling();
    if (doNotFireEvents)
    {
        try
        {
            rh.DisableEventFiring();
            item.SystemUpdate(incrementListItemVersion);
        }
        finally
        {
            rh.EnableEventFiring();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        item.SystemUpdate(incrementListItemVersion);
    }
}

internal class SPItemEventReceiverHandling : SPItemEventReceiver
{
    public new void DisableEventFiring()
    {
        base.DisableEventFiring();
    }

    public new void EnableEventFiring()
    {
        base.EnableEventFiring();
    }
}
```

You should use this method to update item in your workflow. In this case the event does not fired. So the workflow does not started )

Comment: If I understand the problem right the workflow is the cause of the problem - not the event receiver.

Comment: the problem is in code that invokes item.Update() on item which is processed by workflow. If you invoke this method the trigger for workflow that is configured to start on item update are executed.

Comment: Do I understand right that your code may be used outside event reciever ItemAdded etc. event and will work in the same DisableEventFiring manner as inside event receiver?

Comment: I have to mention here that to update the item I am using Client Object Model of SharePoint 2010.

Comment: @Alexander: I've examined your example for disable event firing outside an event receiver and can agree now that it must be the simplest way to resolve discussed issue. I've upvoted your answer. :)

Comment: That is not working with client object model I have tested it

Comment: I do not familiar with client object in this issue... Thus I only can suggest you to use http handler insted of COM for item update.

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways to prevent it is to create a special boolean column and to use it as flag. You can set it from the workflow and then check it in event receiver - if it's true you need to set it to false in event receiver and return with no further action. It's no so elegant but it works. :)